# How do I show that $\lim_{y\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(X\geq y)\cdot e^{(ky)}=0$ if $\mathbb{E}[e^{(kX)}]<\infty$ for some $k$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable such that $\mathbb{E}[e^{(kX)}]<\infty$ for some $k>0$.

Then we have to prove that $$\lim_{y\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(X\geq y)\cdot e^{(ky)}=0.$$

What I have tried is that If I use the method used to prove Markov's inequality then I get that $$P(X\geq y)\leq \frac{1}{e^{kt}}\mathbb{E}[e^{kX}].$$

So $$ e^{yk}P(X\geq y)\leq M\,\,\forall y\,\,such\,\,that\,\, y<X. $$ Here $M=\mathbb{E}[e^{(kX)}]$ .

So $$\lim_{y\to\infty}e^{yk}P(X\geq y)\leq M.$$ This gives that the limit is finite.

But how do I proceed from here if I have to show that the limit is $0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another way to approach the problem:

The assumption gives
$$ \mathbf{E} e^{kX} = \int_0^\infty e^{kx }d\mathbf{P}_X(x) < \infty, $$
where $\mathbf{P}_X$ is the measure defined by $\mathbf{P}_X(E) = \mathbf{P}(X \in E)$ for every measurable set.

Then for every $y > 0$ montonicity of the integral yields
$$ \mathbf{P}(X \geq y) e^{ky} = \int_y^\infty e^{ky} d\mathbf{P}_X(x) \leq \int_y^\infty e^{kx} d\mathbf{P}_X(x). $$
Since $\int_0^\infty e^{kx }d\mathbf{P}_X(x)$ is finite the RHS tends to zero for $y \rightarrow \infty$. But then the LHS has to converge to zero as well, as it is nonnegative.

Comment: I edited to make that clear. However, one could write $dF_X(x)$ instead.

Comment: @bs_math $\mathbb{P}(X\geq y) e^{ky}<\infty $ why then as $y\rightarrow \infty$ the LHS goes to zero, it couldn't converge to a non zero constant?? This question might me stupid, but I would really like to know

Comment: Stupid me, I mistook left and right

Comment: Oh, I see, it will be zero because the lower bound of the integral approaches $\infty$?

Comment: No, the upper bound on the RHS tends to zero by dominated convergence. As the LHS is bounded below by zero, it has to converge to zero as well.